# Writing dataframe to Postgres database psycopg2

Tags: pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to write a pandas DataFrame to a Postgres database.

Code is as below:

```
dbConnection = psycopg2.connect(user = "user1", password = "user1", host = "localhost", port = "5432", database = "postgres")
dbConnection.set_isolation_level(0)
dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
dbCursor.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS FiguresUSA")
dbCursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE FiguresUSA")
dbCursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FiguresUSAByState")
dbCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE FiguresUSAByState(Index integer PRIMARY KEY, Province_State VARCHAR(50), NumberByState integer)"); 

for i in data_pandas.index:
    query = """
    INSERT into FiguresUSAByState(column1, column2, column3) values('%s',%s,%i);
    """ % (data_pandas['Index'], data_pandas['Province_State'], data_pandas['NumberByState'])

dbCursor.execute(query)
```

When I run this, I get an error which just says : "Index". I know its somewhere in my for loop is the problem, is that % notation correct? I am new to Postgres and don't see how that could be correct syntax. I know I can use to_sql but I am trying to use different techniques.

Print out of data_pandas is as below:

[image]

One slight possible anomaly is that there an "index" in the IDE version. Could this be the problem?

[image: IDE VERSION]

Comment: Yes it has to do with the IDE showing that column differently. See my updated answers below for how you can handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [pd.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), you can supply the `index_label` parameter to use that as a column.

```py
data_pandas.to_sql('FiguresUSAByState', con=dbConnection, index_label='Index')
```

If you would prefer to stick with the custom SQL and for loop you have, you will need to [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first.

```py
for row in data_pandas.reset_index().to_dict('rows'):
    query = """
    INSERT into FiguresUSAByState(index, Province_State, NumberByState) values(%i, '%s', %i);
    """ % (row['index'], row['Province_State'], row['NumberByState'])
```

Note that the default name for the new column is `index`, uncapitalized, rather than `Index`.

Comment: I tried that but its giving me the same error unfortunately. Could it be a problem with how those values are declared, i.e. the %s %i etc?

Comment: Can print out your `data_pandas`? Ideally a small sample of 5 or fewer rows that will reproduce the problem. It sounds like the `Index` column may not be in your `DataFrame`, or perhaps it has duplicates that cause trouble with the `PRIMARY KEY` requirement, or perhaps it is not actually an integer, etc.

Comment: I'll add it as an image in the main question. Its getting messy otherwise.

Comment: Please add this, formatted, to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your help - propose a tiny edit to the above query as below: just need to update the column names, change %s to %i and put the apostrophe around the %s.          INSERT into NumberByState(index, Province_State, NumberByState) values(%i,'%s',%i);
        """ % (row['index'], row['Province_State'], row['NumberByState'])
Thanks for your help - marked as solution

Comment: Great! I'm glad that got you unstuck. I have updated according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In the insert statement:

```
query = """
        INSERT into FiguresUSAByState (column1, column2, column3) values ​​('%s',%s,%i);
        """% (data_pandas ['Index'], data_pandas ['Province_State'], data_pandas ['NumberByState'])
```

You have a '%s', I think that is the problem. So remove the quotes

Comment: Hey, thanks for help - I tried that and unfortunately it did not fix it. I suspect that is part of the problem though. I have added a sample of my dataframe to the original question if you want to try reproduce.